# Google Maps API and bandwidth consumption

Tags: php, mysql, hosting, google-maps

I have a site that uses 2 Google Maps APIs.

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js
```

and

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json
```

This "mapper" site communicates with 2 Google Maps APIs, geolocates the user, and extracts data from a MySQL database to display markers in a Google Map around the user.

The site was hosted on Digital Ocean / DigitalOcean. A few days after the site was up Digital Ocean claimed that my site was doing a DDOS attack and took it offline.

It's all original code I wrote and there's nothing malicious in the code.

When I put the site up a second time, a few days later Digital Ocean took it offline again, this time claiming it was "too active" and "disrupting traffic."

I do have the cheapest plan ($5 a month), but their the sign-up process doesn't contain anything explicit and obvious about data transfer caps.

Apparently, Google Maps API queries do something to make your site "too active" and "disrupt traffic". When comparing hosting plans and services, what kinds of features should I focus on to evaluate a host that is better suited for this "mapper" website's needs?

Comment: *"A few days after the site was up Digital Ocean claimed that my site was doing a DDOS attack and they took it offline"* - Who claimed it was a DDoS or who reported they were under attack? Did Google claim it? Did your site require client authentication? Or did it blindly do what any client asks it to do?

Comment: Digital Ocean claimed it. Evidently, that was not true. It was just that the site was "too active" and they used that excuse to take my site offline. The site doesn't need any client authentication. Anyone with a browser could use it (when it was up).

Answer (score 1):

It's likely less about the traffic that it is creating and more about the server load it's creating. Without seeing the code, I can't be of much help but I'd look into how often you are polling and things like that. Try putting it in a VM and seeing what kind of performance impact it's having on the system.

Comment: Thank you so much for the suggestions. I've heard of "polling," never done it, I'll look it up on Google and figure it out. The suggestion about putting it in a VM is an excellent, creative solution.